# Reading from Flash: TMS320F28069M

Tags: microcontroller, ram, texas-instruments, flash-memory, code-composer

I'm using LAUNCHXL-F28069M containing TMS320F28069M ti microcontroller, I've developed a code to derive various parameters like RPM, Direction, etc and displaying it on OLED, the code is all fine though the issue I'm facing is with the board, the program runs all well when I load it into the board but as soon as I reset or cycle power (remove and plug in) the board loses the code, I suppose the code was getting saved in volatile memory, I went through a lot of sites and tried all the suggestions and yet I can't save and run the code from Flash memory, though I feel I'm successfully able to erase and store my code in flash data [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6isOm.png) but yet the board doesn't posts output (verified by seeing no I2C communication for OLED). There are couple of things and as I'm researching more, I'm getting more confused, It would be a great help if you could assist the same.

The methods I've tried are as follow:

- Adding _Flash in [Sysctrl or in predefined symbols](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000-microcontrollers-group/c2000/f/c2000-microcontrollers-forum/539257/f28075-programming-and-running-from-flash)
- Including [Non RAM cmd](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/c2000-microcontrollers-group/c2000/f/c2000-microcontrollers-forum/1262270/tms320f28335-flash-run/4779984?tisearch=e2e-sitesearch&keymatch=RAM%20LNK#4779984) file: [Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY8Ho.jpg)
- Toggling S1 switches in all possible conditions (Though setting switch 3 to 0 disconnects my board, so I could only toggle 1 and 2):  [BOOT SWITCHES](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h9nH.jpg)
- Trying different settings in Debug Configuration, etc.

EDIT: I've realised I'm successfully saving my program into the flash

- [Cleared Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFCM3.png)
- [Programmed Memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv9ep.png)

(cleared memory stayed cleared and programmed stays programmed when I build through RAM_lnk)

So now I know to store the code but yet the code is not getting executed, idk why?